# Gravity for xml drawable

Tags: android, xml, xml-drawable

I want to create a custom View based on `ImageView` to make a widget as below where the drawable source is the camera and the background is the rectangle with the tick sign:

[image: Expected appearance of the widget]

The problems are:

- I can not create the border with the tick sign on the right: the tick is stretched fullscreen instead of staying at the bottom right.
- The tick sign is sometime behind the image if I set it with `android:background`.

---

Here are my `xml` files:

The current border xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="2dip"
            android:color="@color/bg_black"/>
        <padding
            android:left="3dp"
            android:right="3dp"
            android:top="3dp"
            android:bottom="3dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
<item >
    <layer-list >
        <item>
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="2dp"
                    android:color="@color/border_yellow"/>
                <size
                    android:width="37dp"
                    android:height="37dp"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="3dp"
                    android:left="3dp"
                    android:right="3dp"
                    android:top="3dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tick"/>
    </layer-list>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The Image Button xml layout

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/product1"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_rectangle_check"/>
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: where do you use this drawable? post it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Did you mean the layout xml. I posted it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I still wonder the tick sign is behind the image. Because I want it on top Can we use the background with that function? If not how can we implement this function: customize `onDraw` function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the sort of solution you'd be looking for but instead of having an xml file with the styling in it, I believe it would be better to have a layout file which defines your layout for your custom Widget, Something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/customWidgetBox"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/customCheckmark"
       android:gravity="bottom|right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And to the drawable folder you would need to add both the customCheckmark.xml and customWidgetBox.xml

> customCheckmark.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:shape="rectangle">
>     <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_mark">
>         <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/blue_button_border" />
>    </item>
> </shape>
> ```
>
> customWidgetBox.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:shape="rectangle">
>     <item android:drawable="@drawable/camera">
>         <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/blue_button_border" />
>    </item>
> </shape>
> ```

Not sure if this code accomplish exactly what you want, but it'll be a good help to get you started because this is definitely the way to do it! :)

Some links that might be interesting for examples:

[Set border and background color of textView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387366/set-border-and-background-color-of-textview)

[Drawable Resource, Android API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)

[how to put a border around an android textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496269/how-to-put-a-border-around-an-android-textview)

[Tips & Tricks -XML Drawables Part 1](http://android-dev-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.nl/2012/08/xml-drawables-part-i.html)

Comment: I got your idea. Thank you. But it does not match my requirement